# Custom arrows in react slick slider not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, components, slider

"I am trying to use multiple sliders in my component with custom arrows located below each carousel. I have read the documentation, and everything seems to be correct, but clicking the arrows does not work. What could be happening? I am using Next.js 13."

my code:

```
const { locale } = useRouter();
    const dataCurrentLocale = dataCategories[locale as keyof typeof dataCategories];
    const dataProductsCurrentLocale = dataProducts[locale as keyof typeof dataProducts];
    const sliderRef = useRef<any>();


    const next = () => {

      sliderRef.current?.slickNext();
      
    };
   
     const previous = () => {
    sliderRef.current?.slickPrev();
    
    }; 

    const settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: true,
                },
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    };

   

    return (
        <CategoriesPageWrapper>
            <div className="header">
                <h1>{dataCurrentLocale.title}</h1>
            </div>

            {dataProductsCurrentLocale.categories.map((category: any) => {
                return (
                    <div className="category_container" key={category.id}>
                        <div className="category_header">
                            <span>{category.name}</span>
                            <Link href={'/'}>
                                {locale === 'es'
                                    ? `Ver todos los productos de ${category.name}`
                                    : locale === 'cat'
                                    ? ''
                                    : `See all ${category.name} products`}
                            </Link>
                        </div>

                        <Slider {...settings} className="carrousel_container" ref={sliderRef}>
                            {category.subcategories.map((subcategory: any) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={subcategory.query.id}>
                                        <div className="card">
                                            <Link href={'/'}>
                                                <div className="portrait_container">
                                                    <img src={subcategory.portrait}></img>
                                                </div>
                                            </Link>

                                            <div className="link_container">
                                                <Link href={'/'}>
                                                    {locale === 'es'
                                                        ? `Ver ${subcategory.name}`
                                                        : locale === 'cat'
                                                        ? ``
                                                        : `See ${subcategory.name} products`}
                                                </Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })}
                        </Slider>
                        <div className="arrows">
                            <Image
                                src={'/assets/images/icons/slide-black-arrow.png'}
                                width={24}
                                height={10}
                                alt="Prev"
                                onClick={previous} // this is one function
                                className={'prev arrow'}
                            />
                            <Image
                                src={'/assets/images/icons/slide-black-arrow.png'}
                                width={24}
                                height={10}
                                alt="Next"
                                className={'next arrow'}
                                onClick={next} // this is other function
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </CategoriesPageWrapper>
    );
};

export default CategoriesPage;
```

customize my arrows in react slick carrousel

Comment: One of the problem I could think, is that you are mapping `dataProductsCurrentLocale.categories` and using the same `sliderRef` as `ref` for every element, which will in teory, it should contain the last element.

Comment: Thanks so much. I had gone crazy with this, you are right, and I hadn't noticed. It's already resolved!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do like you did.
Instead of this, use this one:

```
const PrevArrow = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image {...props}/>
  )
}
const NextArrow = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image {...props}/>
  )
}
const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    nextArrow: <NextArrow />,
    prevArro: <PrevArrow />,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2,
                infinite: true,
                dots: true,
            },
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 2,
                infinite: true,
                dots: true,
            },
        },
    ],
};
```